# UITableViewController save issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, save, uitableview

I've a UITableViewController which has Edit/Save and cancel buttons. At present I'm displaying 5 row's of custom UITableViewCell's. Custom UITableViewCell contains textfield and label. Let's say if user enters text in 1st table cell and hits "Save" then I'm losing the entered/modified text. Whereas if user hits return key after entering/modifying text then the entered/modified value is captured via:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
.......code exists to capture value here
}
```

but on the other hand if user hits "Save" button without returning the textfield then I'm losing the entered/modified value. What's the best way to capture user's input here:

a) when user returns text field --> which I'm doing already
b) when user hits save button without returning textfield/textview --> ????

thanks in advance,
Rama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep a property that holds the string as it's being entered using a delegate method.  Something like:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSMutableString *testString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.textField.text];
    [testString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    self.stringInProgress = testString;
    return YES;
}
```

Another option might be to call [tableView endEditing] as the first thing to do on a save but I'm not **certain** that fires the textFieldShouldEndEditing: notification.

Comment: +1 I would go for the `[tableView endEditing];` in save. It does in fact fire the `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` method. And it preserves the model string incase the user hits cancel.

Comment: thanks for answers. before calling save, i'm using: [self.tableView endEditing:YES]; but it doesn't work. But Phillip Mills solutions works. However i'm having issues with my textview! textfield is sorted but textview is still pending. thanks

Comment: do you know why textview methods are not firing? a) - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView b) - (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView c) - (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView d) - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)string ?? If I scroll my table view couple times then I'm losing my entered/modified text in textview!!! but textfield is working fine. Thanks

Comment: [self.view endEditing:YES] fires textFieldShouldEndEditing but you then need to call Save manually without using condition: if (!self.editing) {[self save]}

Comment: textViewField.delegate = self; --> forgot to set the delegate! now it works fine.